# Detecting Difference between images in python / pygame

Tags: python, image-processing, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am working on an art project using a Raspberry Pi (Running Rasbian Wheezy). I'm making a timelapse where only the areas of image that have changed are replaced.

The processor gets maxed out and runs quite slow when creating a PixelArray from pixels of two different arrays using an alpha channel to determine which pixel is used:

```
  alphachannelarray = basearray.compare(imgarray, distance=0.08, weights=(0.01, 0.01, 0.01))

  alphachannel = alphachannelarray.make_surface()    

  for col in range (0, 800):
    for cell in range (0, 600):
      if alphachannelarray[col, cell] == alphachannel.map_rgb ((0,0,0)):
            imgarray[col, cell] = imgoldarray[col,cell] #if alpha channel is black use imgold pixel


      elif alphachannelarray[col, cell] == alphachannel.map_rgb ((255,255,255)):
            imgarray[col, cell] = imgarray[col][cell] #il alpha channel is white use img pixel
```

Is there a way in pygame to access all the pixels in an image more quickly than a for loop?

Thanks!
-Tommy

Comment: You may get a better response if you a) ask about one problem at a time, b) post the minimum amount of code necessary to show the problem and c) describe whatever debugging and troubleshooting you've already done

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You could consider breaking up the question into 2 separate questions (the performance vs the lack of updating). Also, if you are more specific on what you expect, you increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! Should I edit my original question or post new ones? Is one or the other bad etiquette?

Comment: Editing your question is the best way to go. I would edit this one to focus on the lack of updating, then when you have something that actually works you can post a new question if you still have performance issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full answer, but a few ideas/notes:

1. I'm not sure exactly what you're doing with the alpha blitting. You might be better off blitting a sub-rect of the image, if you don't need alpha. I think you're saving a external image that is a 'diff', leaving other pixels transparent?
2. Try the slice notation for accessing PixelArray instead of tuples. `imgarray[x:y] = (255,255,0)` vs `imgarray[x, y] = (255, 255, 0)` incase that is preventing numpy arrays from being used. More examples: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#pygame.PixelArray
3. [PixelArray.compare (docs)](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#PixelArray.compare) uses a threshold. You might be looking for no threshold comparison.

Comment: Thanks, monkey! You are correct in 1.,I'm trying to make certain pixels transparent  (the ones that don't match an earlier image).
Slice notation doesn't work quite so easily with PixelArray, and accessing each pixel takes quite a lot of processing.

I will look further into no threshold comparison. Thanks again!

Comment: I found that using surfarray and accessing the numpy.putmask works quite quickly!
  numpy.putmask(img3d, alphachannel3d == [0,0,0], imgold3d) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the pixels and only change those that dont match, you dont have to keep redrawing transparent pixels over the other ones.